# Weird exception in Application subclass

Tags: java, android

Crashlytics sent me a stacktrace that I do not understand and that I cannot simulate:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at lelisoft.com.lelimath.helpers.LeliMathApp.playSound(LeliMathApp.java:81)
at lelisoft.com.lelimath.fragment.PuzzleFragment$HandleClick.onClick(PuzzleFragment.java:158)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4276)
```

LeliMath is android Application subclass which shall be initialized just once. I understand that it is a kind of singleton. The code where it fails is initialized at creation and never nulled.

```
public class LeliMathApp extends Application  {
  private Map<Integer, Integer> mSounds = new HashMap<>();
  private boolean soundEnabled;

public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    soundEnabled = sharedPref.getBoolean(GamePreferenceActivity.KEY_SOUND_ENABLED, true);
    setSoundLevel(sharedPref.getInt(GamePreferenceActivity.KEY_SOUND_LEVEL, 50));
    toggleSound(soundEnabled);
}

public void playSound(int resourceId) {
    if (soundEnabled) {
        int soundId = mSounds.get(resourceId); // NPE here
        mShortPlayer.play(soundId, soundLevel, soundLevel, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}

public void toggleSound(boolean state) {
    log.debug("Toggle sound support");
    if (! state && mShortPlayer != null) {
        mShortPlayer.release();
        mShortPlayer = null;
        mSounds.clear();
    } else if (state && mShortPlayer == null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            mShortPlayer = new SoundPool.Builder().build();
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            mShortPlayer = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }
        mSounds.put(R.raw.correct, this.mShortPlayer.load(this, R.raw.correct, 1));
        mSounds.put(R.raw.incorrect, this.mShortPlayer.load(this, R.raw.incorrect, 1));
        mSounds.put(R.raw.victory, this.mShortPlayer.load(this, R.raw.victory, 1));
    }
}
```

It cannot fail on NPE but it does. Any idea? I would love to see the logs but I do not know the user with this error.

Update: this is a list of calls to this method

```
LeliMathApp.getInstance().playSound(R.raw.correct);
LeliMathApp.getInstance().playSound(R.raw.incorrect);
LeliMathApp.getInstance().playSound(R.raw.victory);
```

Comment: From where do yo call `playSound()`?

Comment: from onClick handler, see stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mSounds.get(resourceId); returns null when the key is not present in the hashmap. Hence the null pointer exception.

To solve this u need to do something like this.

```
int soundId = -1;

Integer tempSoundId = mSounds.get(resourceId);
if(tempSoundId != null)
  soundId = tempSoundId;
```

> This is an expected java behaviour since we are trying to unbox a null
>   value.

Comment: Good idea. I thought that mSounds is null. It may be that resourceId is not found.

Comment: Hope this works out for you now and you are able to simulate it :)

Comment: yes.. but just try calling playSound with a incorrect resource id and you will know if this was the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, it may be a initialization problem. That it is not called even if it should. Either from constructor or from OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Thanks, I upvote you.

Comment: Integer x = null;
  int y = x; This is a classic example. It crashes in this line with null pointer exception. Exact thing is happening in your case.

Comment: I added workaround so it does not crashes but I have no idea of a root cause. I still think that it could not happen :-)